# Name of interface can be a returntype?

Tags: java

```
public interface Shape {
       void draw();
    }



class Square implements Shape {

   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Inside Rectangle::draw() method.");
   }
}


class ShapeFactory {

   //use getShape method to get object of type shape 
   public Shape getShape(String shapeType){
      if(shapeType == null){
         return null;
      }     




       else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("SQUARE")){
         return new Square();
      }

      return null;
   }
}

public class FactoryPatternDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ShapeFactory shapeFactory = new ShapeFactory();

      //get an object of Square and call its draw method.
      Shape shape1 = shapeFactory.getShape("Square");

      //call draw method of square
      shape1.draw();


   }
}
```

**I got this code while learning design pattern and in this code, the return type of the `getShape` method is `Shape` (an interface)**.

So can an interface type be set as a return type of another method?

Comment: Sure. This is a solid example of inheritance. This is very similar to an abstract parent class and multiple child classes. It works in the same manner, but in your example an interface makes the most sense since the parent requires no unique functionality of itself.

Answer (score 2):

> So, can an interface type be set as a return type of another method?

Yes, in Java, one can always declare the return value of any method to be interface type. To quote the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html) (emphasis mine):

> An interface declaration introduces a new **reference type** whose members are classes, interfaces, constants, and methods. This type has no instance variables, and typically declares one or more abstract methods; **otherwise unrelated classes can implement the interface by providing implementations for its abstract methods**. Interfaces may not be directly instantiated.

In Java, there are two *kinds* of types:

1. Primitive types (`byte, short, int, long, float, double, and boolean` only)
2. Reference types (can be arbitrarily many)

Thus, when you have an interface `Shape`, you can declare methods whose return type (of *Reference* kind) is `Shape`. Since `Shape` is an interface, you can not direct instantiate it since it is `abstract` (if you do `Shape abstractShape = new Shape();` you will get a compiler error: `Shape is abstract; cannot be instantiated`). In this regard, the return type declaration is analogous to variable type declaration.

There is nothing specific to the Factory design pattern here, although it is of particular importance in implementing a Factory. In general, whenever you believe that *coding to interfaces* is a good practice in a particular functionality, declaring return types to be interfaces enables that practice.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a good practice since you are programming for an Interface rather than Classes, what hides the details of the implementation and makes your code a lot easier to be maintained. Imagine this: you have an Interface X, two Classes that implement it (A and B) and another Class (C) that has a method called foo(). Since both classes A and B implement X, the return of foo() can be X what allows you to return both A or B objects. 
In Java, when you have a Class that implements an Interface, an instance of that Class is also an instance of that Interface, that's why you can use an Interface as a return type.

To test what I said, you can create an Interface called MyInterface and a Class TestClass that implements MyInterface. If you create an instance of TestClass (let's say "myClass"), if you compile and run this code, you can check it:

```
  if (myClass instanceof MyInterface) {
         System.out.println("Hey, I'm an instance of MyInterface!");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamental to the factory method pattern:
a factory method typically returns an interface type,
and the specific class that will be returned is a hidden implementation detail.

A classic example of this is the various factory methods in `java.util.Collections`, for example `emptyList`, `singletonList`, and so on.
These methods return `List` type, and the implementation is completely hidden.

Another good example is the factory methods in `java.util.EnumSet`,
with return type `EnumSet`, which is an `abstract` class.
Depending on the size of the underlying enum type, the methods will return a `RegularEnumSet` instance if the underlying enum type contains 64 or fewer elements (as most enum types do), or else a `JumboEnumSet` instance.
These are two different implementations of `EnumSet`. The exact type is irrelevant to clients, an implementation detail that can be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of abstraction, "Hiding Actual implementation".